# for loop not iterating over last element of 2D array in google app script (GAS)

Tags: arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, iteration

I am working on a script that, in part, takes an array of names, compares each name to column A in a sheet, and returns with a row matched value in column B.  (Like the vLookup command in sheets)

The setup

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var clientsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Clients");
  var cRow = clientsSheet.getLastRow();
  var cColumn=clientsSheet.getLastColumn();
  var cData=clientsSheet.getRange(1,1,cRow,cColumn).getValues(); //create array of client data
```

The trouble code

```
//put each client on their own row and add hour
for(i=0; i < client.length; ++i){
var cl = client[i]

//iterate over array of clients (column A) and hours (Column B) to find match and log the number in column B
for(j=0;j<cData.length;++j){
 if (cData[j][0]==cl){
    var hour = cData[j][1]; 

     }
   }
//return the matched values
Logger.log(cl+" - "+hour);
}
```

The var 'client' is an array that was split from a list of names in a single cell that are separated by commas (see whole code below)

At the moment it works great except that it misses the last element in the array.

for example:

if I have a sheet with two columns and three rows like so:

```
A    1
B    2
C    3
```

I would get back

```
A-1
B-2
C-
```

It is missing that last piece on the last element - it should be

```
A-1
B-2
C-3
```

I am stumped, and I know that it must be some simple little thing.

Any help would be amazing
Thanks!

The Code:

```js
function logClients()

/*
Take data from a google form check box submissions.  Check box submissions put all checked answers into a single cell separated by a comma.  The function first takes the most recently submitted row, removes unneeded spaces, and splits each element into its own part of an array. 

Then, the function compares each clients name in the array to a sheet with other info, such as the default number of hours we meet.  It takes the clients name, the date of submission, and the hours, and logs them on a new row in two different sheets, the Hours sheet and the Trans Log sheet.
*/

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var logSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Log");  //Raw data from the Google form
var hourSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Hours"); //logged data for my records, separated into individual clients
var transLog = ss.getSheetByName("Trans Log"); // logged data minus "other" catagory 
var clientsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Clients"); //sheet containing all clients names and the typical hours we meet
var lRow = logSheet.getLastRow();
var hRow = hourSheet.getLastRow();
var tRow = transLog.getLastRow();
var cRow = clientsSheet.getLastRow();
var cColumn = clientsSheet.getLastColumn();


var cData = clientsSheet.getRange(1, 1, cRow, cColumn).getValues();


//get list of clients from cell and split it into an array
var Client = logSheet.getRange(lRow, 2).getValue().replace(", ", ","); //remove all spaces after a comma
var client = Client.split(",");

//get "other" information and do the same
var Other = logSheet.getRange(lRow, 5).getValue().replace(", ", ",");
var other = Other.split(",");




//check the date and set to today if nothing else has been entered
var dcell = logSheet.getRange(lRow, 4).getValue();
var date = new Date()
if (dcell == "") {} else if (dcell == "Yesterday") {
  date = new Date(date.getTime() - 1 * (24 * 3600 * 1000));
} else {
  date = dcell
}

var date = Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT-8", "MM/dd/yy"); //format date




//put each client on their own row
for (i = 0; i < client.length; ++i) {


  var cl = client[i]
  var hour = logSheet.getRange(lRow, 3).getValue(); //hours 

  if (hour == !"") {
    break;
  }
  for (j = 0; j < cData.length; ++j) {
    if (cData[j][0] == cl) {
      var hour = cData[j][1];

    }
  }
  Logger.log(date + " - " + cl + " - " + hour);
  hourSheet.appendRow([date,cl, hour]);
  transLog.appendRow([date, cl, hour]);
}


//put each client on their own row
for (i = 0; i < other.length; i++) {
  hourSheet.appendRow([date, other[i], getHour(client[i])]);
}


} //end of function
``
```

This is a code that I have been working on to teach myself Java and Apps-script

Comment: The outer loop, loops through `client`.  You aren't showing how you get `client`.  The inner loop gets the hour: `var hour = cData[j][1];`, but then what are you doing with `hour`?   With your example code, we must assume that the original data was retrieved correctly.  But we have no way of knowing that.  The first thing that comes to mind is that your `for` loop is ending before the last row is processed, but with the information provide, there is no way to determine that.  Maybe "hard code" come data for testing:  `var cData = ['one','two','three','four'];`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I tried to keep it simple but I see that I left out some important info.  I have added the raw code to the bottom of the post.  Hope that it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Yup, simple mistake.

Not all of the spaces before each name were being removed from the array, so the if statement would skip right over them because they were not a true match